# Please explain this particular proof of no polynomial can only produce primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I understand that similar questions have been asked and answered in the past. I need someone to break the proof down to a level where I can see it explicitly. I am not a math graduate, just a hobbyist, so certain things which are apparent to somebody from a math background may not be that apparent to me. Below is the proof and inline my comments on what I specifically do not get.

`Let f(0)=p be a prime.` OK!

`Obviously, f(kp)=f(0)=0(mod p), so p|f(kp).` I suppose it can be proved that `f(kp)` contains a factor of p. So `p|f(kp)`

`Since f is a Prime-Generating Polynomial, f(kp) can only be p, 0, or -p.` Did not understand this.

`But there's at most 3n values of k which f(kp)=0,p,-p(n is the degree of f)
Contradiction.`  Did not follow this

Comment: It does not say that $f(kp) = f(0)$. It says that these are both $0$ mod $p$.

Comment: Using standard notation, your second sentence in the proof should read:

"Obviously, $f(kp) \equiv f(0) \equiv 0 \pmod p$, so $p \mid f(kp)$."

In other words, since $kp$ leaves a remainder of $0$ when divided by $p$,  therefore, $f(kp) \equiv f(0) = p \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Comment: For the last part, a degree $n$ polynomial has at most $n$ roots by the the fundamental theorem of algebra. So there are at most $n$ values of $k$ for which $f(kp)=0$ and similarly for $p$ and $-p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line does not say that $f(kp) = f(0)$, it says that $$f(kp)=f(0)\mod p$$

which is obvious if you write out $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_nx^n$ and then see that $f(x) = a_0 + x\cdot g(x)$ for some function $g(x)$. Then,

$$f(kp) = a_0 + kp\cdot(g(kp)) = a_0 + p\cdot C$$
for some constant $C$, meaning that $f(kp)=a_0\mod p$.

---

The second thing is that since $f$ is a prime generating polynomial, you know that $f(kp)$ is either a prime, a negative prime or $0$. Also, $p$ divides $f(kp)$, so if $f(kp)$ is a prime, it must be $p$ or $-p$ because that is the only prime divisible by $p$.

---

The last line follows from the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ can only have $n$ zeroes. So, the polynomial $f+(x) = f(x) - p$ can also only have $n$ zeroes (therefore, $f(x) = p$ for only $n$ values of $x$) and $f_-(x) = f(x) + p$ can also only have $n$ zeroes (therefore, $f(x) = -p$ for only $n$ values of $x$).

---

Also, sorry to say this, but if this proof is not obvious to you, you are obviously reading a book that is (currently) above your skill level.

Comment: I think OP specified that $n$ is the degree of $f$.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Yeah, noticed and fixed.